# $http.get success method not called

Tags: angularjs, http

I am new to AngularJS & NodeJS. I am trying to get a API response from NodeJS and display it in angular. I am using $http to make API call. Below is my nodeJS code.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/employees',function(req,res)
{
 console.log("Test Output :");
 res.status(200).send('Hello User');
});
app.listen(8080);
```

Below is my angular code

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp',[]).controller('myappController',    ['$scope','$http',function ($scope,$http){
$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/employees')
    .then(function(response)
    {
         window.alert("Success");
         $scope.emdata=response.data;
    },function(errorresponse)
    {
         window.alert("Error");
         $scope.emdata=errorresponse.status;
    });
}]);
```

I am using expression `{{emdata}}` in HTML page. When I open the HTML page I can see the console output "Test Output " in NodeJS terminal which means the API is getting called but I dont see "Hello User" in HTML page. It looks like the success function in `$http.get` is not getting called and only the error function is getting called. So I see an alert window with "Error" whenever I open the HTML page and response status as -1 in the place of `{{emdata}}`.

When I tried making the API call using Postman I get correct response with status 200. So I am wondering what is wrong?

Comment: Hey bro try this  :`$http.get('/employees/', $scope.initial).success(function(response)
            {  });` and try sending a json response perhaps from the server because that way it stays neat and clean. `res.json({status: 200, message: 'message' }); `

Comment: @GandalftheWhite `.success` and `.error` are deprecated

Comment: I never knew. What is the alternative then, the format he is using? It don't look that neat or an upgrade for sure.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite Yes, [an explanation to deprecation reason](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35331339/6275781).

Comment: If you open html page in your browser from filesystem and then try to get from nodejs server so you can face the CORS problem. Just open browser console (ctrl + shift + j in chrome) and check network request plus js errors

Answer (score 0):

Check headers, i.e. what format is accepted by $http request and the format of the response (JSON, plain text, etc).

Fix value in

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common
```

or set needed one in

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { ... };
```

or just use

```
var requestParams = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: '...',
    headers: {
        ...
    }
};
$http(requestParams).then(...);
```

Take a look at **Setting HTTP Headers** in [official manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for more details.